# Multiple Firebase projects (in multiple Firebase accounts) in one app

Tags: android, ios, firebase

I'm a newbie here.

I was reading here https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects#use_multiple_projects_in_your_application
and here https://medium.com/@mmert1988/using-multiple-firebase-projects-in-your-android-app-88241b10d81c

But I didn't understand if is possible to connect one app to different projects even if they are in different Firebase accounts.

Comment: yes it is possible but it will be for different builds/flavors of the app. Can you tell me what use case needs you to do this? There might be a better solution.

Comment: @rbd_sqrl I'm building an app that based on which button a user pressed (and what credentials a user enters), makes him communicate with a different project in a different firebase account. I know it sounds strange but I have a good reason to do this.

Comment: don't know if this will work but you can give this a shot.

Have 2 firebase projects in diff accounts with this same application id (same as the android app), host the json file for the app on your backend. when the user clicks on the button, download the correct json and replace the existing json (could be a dummy) with one you downloaded

Comment: Thank you very much :) I’ll try it later